# Type equality in higher order kleisli (scala)

Tags: scala, category-theory, higher-kinded-types

The Story so far -

```
type :**:[F[_], G[_]] = ({ type λ[α] = F[G[α]] })

trait HBind[M[_]] extends HFunctor[M] {
  def hbind[F[_], G[_]](f: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ)(implicit MG: Functor[(M :**: G)#λ], F: Functor[F], G: Functor[G]): (M :**: F)#λ ~> (M :**: G)#λ

  def hjoin[F[_]: Functor]: (M :**: (M :**: F)#λ)#λ ~> (M :**: F)#λ

  def hflatMap[F[_], G[_], A](fa: M[F[A]])(f: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ)(implicit MG: Functor[(M :**: G)#λ], F: Functor[F], G: Functor[G]): M[G[A]] = hbind(f)(MG, F, G)(fa)

  def hflatten[F[_]: Functor, A](m: M[M[F[A]]]): M[F[A]] = hjoin(implicitly[Functor[F]])(m)

}
```

...

```
trait HMonad[M[_]] extends HBind[M] with HPointed[M]


final class HKleisli[M[_], F[_], G[_]](val run: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ) extends AnyVal {
  import HKleisli.hkleisli
  def apply[A](x: F[A]): M[G[A]] = run(x)
  def hflatMap[K[_]](phi: G ~> ({ type λ[α] = F ~> (M :**: K)#λ })#λ)(implicit M: HMonad[M], H: Functor[(M :**: K)#λ], F: Functor[F], G: Functor[G], K: Functor[K]): HKleisli[M, F, K] =
  hkleisli({
    val psi: (F ~> (M :**: K)#λ) =
      new (F ~> (M :**: K)#λ) {
        def apply[A](fa: F[A]) =
          M.hflatMap(run(fa)) {
            //hole: G ~> [α]M[K[α]]
            val gmk: (G ~> (M :**: K)#λ) =
              new (G ~> (M :**: K)#λ) {
                def apply[A](ga: G[A]) = {
                  val fmk: F ~> (M :**: K)#λ = phi(ga)
                  hkleisli(fmk).run(fa)  // type mismatch; found : fa.type (with underlying type F[A]) required: F[A]
                }
              }
            gmk
          }
      }
    psi
  })

}

object HKleisli {
  def apply[M[_], F[_], G[_]](k: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ) = new HKleisli(k)
  def hkleisli[M[_], F[_], G[_]](k: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ) = apply(k)
}
```

The Problem,

Now as far as the point of all this goes, there's two objectives, first I'm interested in implementing a 2-category in scala (so far I've been very successful {I'm of the opinion that programs might be designed by drawing & composing diagrams in suitable categories Scala has a BiCCC 2-Category structure I've observed (I'm pretty sure at least)}), second Generic programming,
the Free Monad is a higher order monad `HMonad` yoneda and coyoneda have `HFunctor` instances, and I wondered what a `HKleisli` would look like.

Now I'm stuck at an issue with the `A` parameter's shadowing each other and creating the F[A]-not-F[A] issue. now my first thought is to lace an implicit `Leibniz[F[A], F[A']]` (A' is pseudo code) and use in hopes that I can use that to witness the equality of [A]F[A] [A']F[A'], but I haven't yet figured out how that would work or if it's even sufficient, and I'm also wondering if I've just been drilling away at this too long and am missing some obvious rewriting that gets me where I'm trying to go so I'm opening it up to the good people here. I would like if it's at all possible any help and as much detail as possible as to how to make this happen and it is my hope that any thoughts on higher order categorical abstractions will be shared.

Answer (score 0):

So... there's still testing to be done, but for the mean time, I win. Notice the resemblance to normal kleisli arrow bind. The problem wasn't quantified type equality, well it was but the problem was more with nesting, this version is like 2 levels more shallow, and bears a strong resemblance to bid via join, funny thing is I didn't notice till after. I'll leave this question open a while in case some one stumbles along and has a better answer than me.
as far as the `/@>` goes that's just a little compose `·` stand in for scala. I defined it directly on `~>` and wrote an implicit conversion for functions.

```
    final class HKleisli[M[_], F[_], G[_]](val run: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ) extends AnyVal {
      import HKleisli.hkleisli
      def apply[A](x: F[A]): M[G[A]] = run(x)

      final def >=>[K[_]](that: HKleisli[M, G, K])(implicit M: HMonad[M], G: Functor[G], K: Functor[K]): HKleisli[M, F, K] = {
        hkleisli({
          val phi =
            new (F ~> (M :**: K)#λ) {
             def apply[A](fa: F[A]) = {
               M.hbind(that.run)(G, K)(run(fa))
           }
        }
      phi
     })
   }

   final def hbind[K[_]](phi: G ~> ({ type λ[α] = F ~> (M :**: K)#λ })#λ)(implicit M: HMonad[M], K: Functor[K]): HKleisli[M, F, K] = {
   hkleisli({
     val psi =
      new (F ~> (M :**: K)#λ) {
      def apply[A](fa: F[A]) =
        M.hjoin(K)(M.map(M.transmap[G, ({ type λ[α] = F ~> (M :**: K)#λ })#λ](phi)(run(fa))) { (nt: F ~> (M :**: K)#λ) => nt(fa) })
     }
     psi
   })
  }

  final def local[X[_]](f: X ~> F) = hkleisli { 
    val phi = 
      new (X ~> (M:**:G)#λ) {
       def apply[A](x: X[A]) =
        (f /@>[(M:**:G)#λ] run)(x)
    }
    phi
  }
}

object HKleisli {
  def apply[M[_], F[_], G[_]](k: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ) = new HKleisli(k)

  def hkleisli[M[_], F[_], G[_]](k: F ~> (M :**: G)#λ) = apply(k)

  type HKleisliAr[M[_]] = ({ type λ[φ[_], ψ[_]] = HKleisli[M, φ, ψ] })

  def hkIdentity[M[_], F[_]](implicit M: HMonad[M], F: Functor[F]): HKleisli[M, F, F] =
    hkleisli(M.hpoint(F))

  implicit def category[M[_]: HMonad]: HCategory[HKleisliAr[M]#λ] =
    new HCategory[HKleisliAr[M]#λ] {
      def identity[F[_]: Functor] = hkIdentity[M, F]
      def composition[A[_]: Functor, B[_]: Functor, C[_]: Functor](g: HKleisli[M, B, C])(f: HKleisli[M, A, B]) =
        f >=> g
    }
   }
```